# @IBDesignable rendering error in interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, interface-builder

I have a custom view with an image in it.
And i get an error when the interface builder try's to render the Custom view.

I have 6 of these views and i get 3 different errors.

1. > Failed to update auto layout status: interface builder cocoa touch
   >   tool crashed.
2. > Failed to render instance of CustomView: Rendering the view took
   >   longer than 200 ms. Your drawing code may suffer from sloe
   >   performance.
3. > Failed to render instance of CustomView: the designable agent
   >   crashed.

And when i debug the view it crashes on the UIimage propriety. 
and i get an error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

How can i fix this?

Thanks

CODE:

```
@IBDesignable
class UIProgressButton: UIAnimatedButton {

//it crashed here
@IBInspectable
var icon: UIImage = UIImage(named: "feet")!{
    didSet {
        setupView()
    }
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setupView()
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupView()
}


let iconLayer = CALayer()
func setupView(){

    iconLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, self.frame.height-10, self.frame.height-10)
    iconLayer.contents = self.icon.CGImage
    self.layer.addSublayer(iconLayer)
}

}
```

Comment: You should probably paste some code from your CustomView.

Comment: @lchamp I added some code... Thanks

Comment: If anyone would like to see a full example check out the project https://github.com/Adorkable/DorkTiledImageView, uncomment out @IBDesignable and run the Example scheme. It's running into the same issue!

Comment: Was this error ever resolved? I am currently running into a similar problem